# securing view state using ViewstateUserKey property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

On reading about preventing cross-site request forgeries in webforms many authors use statements like this:

To use the ViewStateUserKey property within the Viewstate to protect against spoofed post backs. Add the following in the OnInit virtual method of the Page-derived class (This property must be set in the Page.Init event).

```
protected override OnInit(EventArgs e) {
 base.OnInit(e); 
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID; }
```

The following keys the Viewstate to an individual using a unique value of your choice.

```
 (Page.ViewStateUserKey)
```

**This must be applied in Page_Init because the key has to be provided to ASP.NET before Viewstate is loaded. This option has been available since ASP.NET 1.1**

I have tried to put the above one in Base page, where all pages are deriving from that page  But I am getting error like OnInit must return value

this is my code

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected override OnInit(EventArgs e) {
 base.OnInit(e); 
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID; }

 }
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OnInit declaration is missing the return type void.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
```

Comment: thanks......But I am not able to understand this line(This property must be set in the Page.Init event) and the function must be put in page that is derived from base page right ...